# Changing Footer Link Color Using CSS

Tags: css, web, footer

When I link my footer text to content it changes them to a dark grey because the links on the rest of my website are set to that color. I am looking for some CSS to select and change only my footer links color to #fff , and preferably with a hover color of #fa5705 .

When I use firebug to inspect I can't seem to pick up the right selector and only for the entire website.

[www.jobspark.ca](http://www.jobspark.ca) is the link to my website.

Thanks for taking the time to look into this for me.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want to do:

```
#page-footer a {
     color: #fff;
}

#page-footer a:hover {
     color: #fa5705;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your footer all of your text is contained in < p > are white; but the links them-selves are colored differently. To fix this you can simply add that color attribute to each link element like so:

```
<a style="color:white;" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

Unfortunately you cannot add hover styling in-line you so have to place that CSS else-where and connect to it with an id or class... since you have multiple links to be hovered a CLASS would be preferable over an ID. And while we are using classes lets just put that color styling inside of the class too.

```
<style>   
    .myHover{
      color:#fff;
    }
    .myHover:hover
    {
      color:#fa5705;
    }
</style>

<a class="myHover" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

I tested this CSS and it works; here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwamF/1/).